# How to fetch the orbeon form (yform) data that got stored in database in xml file? How to send that to third party apps?

Tags: forms, orbeon, sap-commerce-cloud

I am Working on yforms with Hybris 6.5. 
Currently I have created forms. After clicking on save button, data is getting saved in my database. Now I am facing problems for:- 1) Fetching the data by fields (as they are in form). 2) Sending that data to any third party apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hybris , they are using hybris database as persistence API for orbeon form. So the orbeon form  data will be stored and retrieved from hybris database. Coming to your issues ,

1) whole xml data will be stored as String . So its not possible to get the particular field separately by getter/setter. But you can parse the whole xml string using some xml parser and get the field you want.

2) There are two ways , you can do it . One is directly from Orbeon forms, sending the submitted directly to some controller and from there parse the data and send to the 3rd party or any other action you want to do . Another way is writing an interceptor in hybris for yformDataModel and do your action . I would prefer thge

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 main ways for you to access the XML data captured based on the answers provided by users to your forms:

1. You can setup Orbeon Forms to send that data to a service you provide when users submit the form.
2. You can call a REST API provided by Orbeon Forms to access the data it stored in the database.
3. You can access the database directly.

For more on this, see [Accessing Data](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/overview/accessing-data.html).

Comment: Can we use these options with yForms?.

Comment: @vipink. I am not sure how persistence is done in the integration SAP Hybris did with Orbeon Forms. If they use the standard buttons for save/submit, then you can modify the corresponding processes and use option 1. If they go through the Orbeon Forms persistence API, and provide their own implementation of that API, then you can also use option 2. And finally, they might also provide a way for you to access their data store. So this really is something that you need to check with SAP Hybris support.